# My RecyclerView is lagging despite not having any listeners + imageViews, why is that?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, performance-testing

First off, I've read other posts that have the same problem as me; from what I summed up, the problem is usually because of imageviews/pictures + listeners. But this is not my case. I don't even have listeners created for my `delButton` and `addButton` and I'm still lagging.

What I intend to do:
https://gyazo.com/ff984e87fc11543d44d1b549147f870c

Whenever the **add button** is clicked, a new **listRow** wouldbe created

**This is my RecyclerVIew class:**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.saved_list_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((ViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return SavedLists.mListRow.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView mListTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mListTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.currentLIst);
        }

        public void bindView(int position){
            mListTextView.setText("List # " + position);
        }
    }

}
```

**This is my Acvitiy class**

```
    public class SavedLists extends AppCompatActivity {
       // private yourListNumber[] mHoles = new yourListNumber[0];
        public static final ArrayList<ListRow> mListRow  = new ArrayList<ListRow>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_lists);
            Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addList);



            //RECYCLERADAPTER set-up here:
            final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter());

            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    mListRow.add(new ListRow());

                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter());
                    //instead of repeating these 3 lines of code, you can use refresh
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It because you always reset recyclerView adapter whenever button clicked.
change the onClick listener become like this

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        mListRow.add(new ListRow());

        recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling viewholders method from bindViewolder ? Change it to like this

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
ArrayList<ListRow> adapterListData;

 @Override
 public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

   public void RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<ListRow> mListRow){
    adapterListData = mListRow;
   }

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.saved_list_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.mListTextView.setText("List # " + adapterListData.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return adapterListData.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView mListTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mListTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.currentLIst);
    }
}
```

}

And Dont set recycler adapter twice in activity. And pass your data in the constructor and assign it to a global varaible

```
public class SavedLists extends AppCompatActivity {
   // private yourListNumber[] mHoles = new yourListNumber[0];
    public static final ArrayList<ListRow> mListRow  = new ArrayList<ListRow>();
     RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_lists);
        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addList);



        //RECYCLERADAPTER set-up here:
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter  = new RecyclerAdapter(mListRow);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                mListRow.add(new ListRow());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John! This improves the performance, but it is still laggy, any other ideas?